# How to recover corrupted MP4

Tags: linux, file, ffmpeg, mp4

After moving some mp4 from computer to USB stick, I discovered that my mp4 are corrupted. I guess USB stick is guilty.

However I would like to recover those MP4 files and I tried ffmpeg but without any success.

As I work under Linux, I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i corrupted_video_file.mp4 -c copy fixed_video_file.mp4
```

Is there another way to fix corrupted mp4 files or any other tool ?

thx